# Scroll view resets when scrolling other scroll view

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am optimizing one of my iPhone applications for the iPhone 5. To do this, I have decided to use auto layout.

I have a scroll view which scrolls vertical. In the top of this scroll view and inside the scroll view I have another paging scroll view which scrolls horizontal. This works fine until I scroll vertically in the outer scroll view. Then the inner scroll view will reset to (0, 0) and it seems that the content size will reset as the scroll view is now unscrollable.
I have been struggling with this for hours and hours and I am now out of ideas.

Does anyone have a clue why this is happening? I'ld be happy to show screenshots, code and more if this will give someone an idea of why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating the views programmatically. There was probably something wrong with my constraints but I did not manage to find out what and didn't want to spend more time playing with it when I realized that there were no problems when the views were created programmatically.